# SQL - Get a count from a single table based on certain column criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a "simple" count of users that have >5 accounts tagged to the same UUID.

To do this for one single UUID, I perform the easy query:

```
Select count(user) 
From Ply 
Where Uuid Like 'i~cfe3a1eba3c2469aa3695e34c840fb62cb3e8791%'
```

(I added the % marker because we append extra tags to multiple accounts under the same UUID)

The result in the above query is a result of 5.

To take this to the next level, I want to count the number of users in the entire Ply table who have >5 accounts for 1 UUID.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT substr(uuid,1,42), count(user)
  FROM ply
 GROUP BY substr(uuid,1,42)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

If that is not what you want, it would be very helpful if you could post a table definition (DDL), some sample data (DML), and the output you want.

Comment: Almost; the trouble is that they append extra tags to multiple accounts under the same UUID, so the UUID isn't a UUID really.

Comment: Exactly, so "1" uuid would actually show up in the table as x different varaitions of the uuid..it would be (for example): 1234,1234_1,1234_2, and continue for as long as that user was creating accounts.

Comment: @Stuav - Are the first 42 characters of the `UUID` always the same?

Comment: If your "real" UUID length is always 42, you can just replace uuid in Justin's query with substr(uuid, 1, 42)

Comment: Yes, they are always the same, and then the tag after the original uuid would be an underscore with additional characters

Comment: @Craig - Made that change in my query.